# User Authentication using Angular 2 and Flask

Tags: angular, authentication, flask

I made a application for User login and Registration in Angular 2 but after log in I am not able to authenticate user (i.e. check if user is logged in). I have developed my back end in flask.

Can anyone help how do I maintain authenticity of user.

The login.component.ts is:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';
import {User} from '../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: `./login.component.html`

})
export class LoginComponent  {
    user: User = new User(); 
    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
    onLogin(): void{
        this.auth.login(this.user)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user);

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    }
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {API_URL} from '../env';
import {map,catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  test(): string {
    return 'working';
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };
  private static _handleError(err: Response | any) {
    return throwError(err || 'Error: Unable to complete request.');
  // return "error"
  }
  login(user) : Promise<any>{
      return this.http.post(`${API_URL}/login`,user, this.httpOptions).toPromise()

        catchError(AuthService._handleError)

  }
```

In my flask back end, I have implemented login method as follows:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    data1 = request.get_json(force=True)
    mydoc = mycol.find(data1)
    y = None
    for x in mydoc:
        print(x)
        y = x

    if (y == None):
        return jsonify({'error': 'error'})
    else :
        return jsonify({'done':'done'})
```

Comment: put your code here

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari I have edited the quetion and added some code